# How to integrate test.watch with `iex -S mix phx.server`

Tags: elixir, tdd, phoenix-framework

I can run `iex -S mix phx.server` and it works great: a repl, plus hot code reload, plus webpack running.

In another shell, I can run `mix test` or `mix test.watch` (with the 3rd party library) and *that* works great too.

But how can I have them run in the same shell window, with a single command? So when I change any code it will automatically re-run tests while simultaneously showing changes in the browser.

in config/dev.exs under my app's config, I tried:

```
...
watchers: [
  mix: ["test"],
  node: [...node stuff...]
]
```

and

```
...
watchers: [
  mix: ["test.watch"],
  node: [...node stuff...]
]
```

In both cases, it runs tests once when I first use `iex -S mix phx.server`, but then doesn't respond to changes.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, nevermind. Turns out I just needed to increase the inotify limit.

```sh
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=32768 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

having `mix: ["test.watch"]` inside my config :watchers seems to work now